# How can I convert MD5 hex strings to base-64 MD5 strings?

Tags: passwords, md5, crypt, md5sum

I have a bunch of MD5-hashed passwords which I would like to convert to crypt-style MD5.

If I have the plaintext I can easily create both:

```
% echo -n 'testpass' | md5sum
179ad45c6ce2cb97cf1029e212046e81 -

% echo -n 'testpass' | openssl passwd -1 -stdin -salt ''
$1$$JN/baUhJCUwYKagp48tsP0
```

But how do I convert `179ad45c6ce2cb97cf1029e212046e81` to `JN/baUhJCUwYKagp48tsP0`?

Comment: Don't implement crypto until you understand what it is. Play with it all you want and learn, just don't put this into anything people depend on until you *really* get it.

Answer (score 2):

The first string is in hex and the second string is a base64.

A MD5 hash is a 128bit *number* .. The ways it can chosen to be printed can be either as a hexdecimal string or as a base64 encoded string -- both are just representations of the 128 bit number.

However `ms5sum` and [`openssl passwd`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/passwd.html) will not <s>encrypt</s>hash the the password to the same 128 hash value, so the same password will not yield the same 128bit number, so in your examples one password-hash will not translate to the other

Comment: How does the encryption differ? In both cases there is no salt, what does `openssl passwd` do differently? If it's just additional iterations then I can do that too in the translation.

Comment: The openssl-passwd manual states it is MD5-based, not actually MD5.  I guess reading the source code would tell how it is different.

Comment: @Bruno: I know, I was quoting Soren ;-)

Comment: [Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)#MD5-based_scheme) that first thing md5-crypt does hash passphrase and salt, so there should be a way to convert an MD5-hashed password to an md5-crypt-hashed one.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have some MD5 hashed passwords that you want to convert to "crypt-style" MD5. If that is the case then you're likely wanting to generate a file you can use for authenticating Apache users. Unfortunately, you likely can't do this from plain MD5 hash values.

Apache's MD5-Crypt hash algorithm isn't an MD5 sum of the password alone. Neither is the -1 variant. The two append something to or otherwise modify the input password not including salt to give the resulting hash. If indeed you have the MD5 hash values using the method you describe piping a string to md5sum, that resulting hash cannot be reversed to anything you can then hash to an htpasswd compatible hash.

Sorry